# How to avoid forced dark theme in my app when devices can force it at app level?

Tags: android, android-theme, android-dark-theme

Some devices, like **Poco F2 Pro**, can force dark theme in apps that are not compatible with dark theme.

For example, my app has this theme and is not compatible with dark theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

This is my manifest application part, no dark theme enabled:

```
<application
    android:name=".helpers.CustomApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

The problem is that devices like **Poco F2 Pro**, when forcing dark theme in apps, makes my app to be displayed with incorrect and abnormal colors, breaking the UI.

Can that be avoided?

How to force dark theme: https://www.androidauthority.com/android-q-force-dark-mode-984090

Comment: can you share your manifest file as well

Answer (score 17):

You can disable Force Dark in your app by setting a flag in your theme:

```xml
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">false</item>
</style>
```

Comment: NOTE: You will need to put this into `app/src/main/res/values-v29/styles.xml` if you support a lower Android API minimum than 29. This directory (and the styles defined in it) will only be used on devices that are running 29+.

Answer (score 6):

This is an old question, but I thought to post my solution so it may help others.

Change your app theme parent from

```
parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar"
```

to

```
parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar"
```