# How to avoid forced dark mode in Material theme?

Tags: android, android-layout, material-components-android, android-darkmode

I'm using Material theme. I want my app to be only in light theme (For now we don't have any plans for dark mode). Some devices force dark mode on apps and I want to avoid that.

I have seen [this post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63777438/how-to-avoid-forced-dark-theme-in-my-app-when-devices-can-force-it-at-app-level) and unfortunately it doesn’t work for me.

So, how to solve this?

**Styles.xml**

```
   <resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="materialButtonStyle">@style/ButtonTheme</item>
    </style>

    <style name="LandingTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/White</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/ButtonTheme</item>
    </style>
</resoures>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: Some OEMs provide a dark-mode feature on an *individual-app basis*, which basically doesn't respect the forced-dark mode setting.

In that case, it is best to ignore any issues that relate to it. The user is warned about theming incompatibilities, which is a good thing from their side at the very least, if not respecting this setting.

---

Please do not account for uncontrollable factors such as *overriding* the force dark mode option (available inside Developer Options from Android 10+), **which makes the opt-in/out effectively useless**.

The feature is more of a trial-and-error, replacing light elements with their dark counterparts (basic but vague explanation, agreed) which may make-or-break an Application's User Experience.

There's a reason why it is meant only for Developers, and not made available as a "User" feature.

Comment: Actually I am not looking for that ( Overriding the force dark mode option of developer options). I'm  looking for overriding the dark mode which is on Settings (the default one not developer options)

Comment: I don't think enabling Dark Mode in System "forces" an app to go Dark. In fact, Developers have to implement `DayNight` themes in order to follow system's dark mode setting - [source](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/darktheme#supporting_dark_theme_in_your_app).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link! In my particular case, enabling darkmode on my Xiaomi phone results in the app being in dark mode. May be it's an OEM issue?

Comment: Ah, seems that this MIUI feature doesn't respect the setting. Well, that's OEM Aggressiveness for you.

Comment: You can safely ignore this, since there's nothing that can be done about it. It's "force dark mode" just pulled out of Developer Options.

Comment: May be that's  the only option :(

Comment: At least they warn the user about incompatibility issues, which makes it easier for you for pointing out that it cannot be termed as an issue.